# error:0409A06E:rsa routines:RSA_padding_add_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:data too large for key size

Tags: node.js, express, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I have JWT token and I want to decrypt it in Node/Express app using crypto module using public/private RSA keys.

**encrypt.js**

```
const encrypt = (plainText) => {
    const cipherText = crypto.publicEncrypt({
        key: publicKey
    },

        Buffer.from(plainText)

    )

    return cipherText.toString("base64")
}


encrypt(payload.JWToken);   // Not Working
```

It throws below error,

> error:0409A06E:rsa routines:RSA_padding_add_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:data too large for key size

```
encrypt("sensitive information")   // works with simple short text
```

Is there any simple way to encrypt long text/string ? because I have some complex objects which I want to decrypt in my app at some point of time.

One solution is to encrypt long text using **symmetric key (SK)**.

Problem with symmetric key approach is: I have to pass SK in each API request. I understand, I can encrypt SK as well. But unfortunately I have a use case where I have some users using only POSTMAN to get data. If I use symmetric key approach, I will have to share the key with them. I don't want to do it.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using a well mantained and stable library like https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken ?

Comment: I use jsonwebtoken in nodejs. It is about securing JWT token while sending it from FE. I want to send encrypted JWT token to backend from FE. But the problem is, in BE, I'm not able to encrypt simple JWT token.